# initialize instance variables on Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm developing an iPhone 3.1.3 application and
I have the following header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface VoiceTest01ViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UITextView *volumeTextView;
    BOOL isListening;
    NSTimer *soundTimer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *volumeTextView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *soundTimer;

- (IBAction)btnStartClicked:(id)sender;

@end
```

And .m file is:

```
#import "VoiceTest01ViewController.h"

@implementation VoiceTest01ViewController

@synthesize volumeTextView;
@synthesize soundTimer;

...
```

How can I set `isListening` up to false at start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the boolean value in your viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  isListening = NO;
  //Something
}
```

Comment: Yea - @VansFannel, be sure to check out the UIViewController documentation for this as to why this is the case for this type of class. :)

Comment: This is so lame -- not your answer, @iPrabu, which is correct, but the fact that the objective-c language doesn't let you specify initializers for instance variables.  The fact that you have to do it in some OS- and app-specific way is just sad (or override the designated initializer as @DarkDust says, but that's even more of a pain just to add what should be a simple `= 1`).

Answer (score 6):

All instance variables are set to 0/NULL/nil by default, which in the case of a `BOOL` means `NO`. So it already is `NO` (or false) by default.

If you need any other value then you need to override the designated initializer(s), most of the time `init`, and set the default value there.

Answer (score 2):

The default value for a BOOL field is False, but it's a good place set it in the "viewDidLoad" just as @BuildSucceeded sugest

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

1) `init` is a good place, like below, but if you are using story board this `init` method won't be called.

```
- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        isListening = NO;
    }
    return self;
}
```

2) 
`initWithCoder` is a good place for your code if you are using storyboard of course your sdk is 3.0, i believe it has not storyboard at that time, but just in case anyone need it:

```
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if (self) {
        isListening = NO;
    }
    return self;
}
```

3) If your viewcontroller will be init from nib file:

```
- (id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
         isListening = NO;
    }
}
```